# JSON parse error in Informatica HTTP transformation for Graphql API

Tags: json, api, http, graphql, informatica

I have created a mapping with http transformation POST method to call a graphql API to read data. The input filter to be passed is of graphql json format..ie. with query, variables and operationName. I have filled the headers Content-Type, Authorization, Accept and Accept-Encoding in the same order. For the Input field, I have named it as 'data' and passed the json input as string in the Default Value field. It is of format:
{"query":"..." ,"variables":null,"operationName":"..."}
But I am getting error as:
Status:500; error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token 'data': was expecting ('true' ,'false' or 'null'')......line 1 column 5

Not sure where I am going wrong. Should Input field have an alias HTTP Name? Would be happy to know your views. Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly as it says: there is a 'data' key in your input. And the service was not expecting it. Please check the swagger or try calling the service with Postman or some other tool, to create a valid sample test request.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like issue was with the POST method. It was expecting Simple Post since there was only one input. On changing it, mapping was able to retrieve data